# gpgkeys not found on keyserver

Tags: 12.04, gnupg, keyserver

So this error has been popping up a lot so I thought I'd resolve it:

```
W: GPG error: http://cfengine.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 535C743689107B44
```

So I did some research and tried these solutions

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recV 535C743689107B44
```

and

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 535C743689107B44
```

both of which terminated with this message

```
gpgkeys: key 535C743689107B44 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Any insights are appreciated

Comment: look at answer 1
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283628/problem-with-public-key-on-apt-get-update this probem resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the GPG-key is not there (anymore).

If you want to install CFEngine Community Linux Packages:
from(http://cfengine.com/cfengine-linux-distros)

exerpt:
CFEngine 3 Linux Distributions:
Download and install the CFEngine GPG key(changed # to sudo because of formating):

> sudo wget http://cfengine.com/pub/gpg.key
>
> sudo apt-key add gpg.key
>
> sudo rm gpg.key

Add the repository to the apt list of sources. If the add-apt-repository utility is installed on your system, you may simply run:

> sudo add-apt-repository http://cfengine.com/pub/apt

... follow instructions on the website.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach mentioned in this [link](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/04/w-gpg-error-httpppalaunchpadnet-precise.html) worked for me. Manually download the key and add it. The link provides step by step procedure to fix the error happening due to missing key.